# About the double integral and fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=1 $ if $x= \frac{m}{n} ,y= \frac{q}{n}, (m,n)=(q,n)=1 $ otherwise $f(x,y) =0$
,Now which of following options is true ?

I think because $f(x,y) =0 ,a.e$ then option 4 is true and because $f$ is not continue so we can't use fobini`s theorem is this true ?

$$1)\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{[0,1 ]}f(x,y)\,\text{d}y\right)\,\text{d}x=1$$

$$2)\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{[0,1]}f(x,y)\,\text{d}y\right)\,\text{d}x=0$$

$$3)\int_{[0,1]\times [0,1]} f(x,y)\,\text{dxdy}=1$$
$$4)\int_{[0,1]\times [0,1]} f(x,y)\,\text{dxdy}=0$$

Comment: $(m,n)=(q,n)=1$?

Comment: You don't need continuity to apply Fubini's Theorem. 2) and 4) are both true and 1) and 3) are false.

Comment: @d.k.o  (a,b) is greatest common divisor (gcd) of a,b.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy . Why 2 is true ? If x be fix and x be irrational we have another answer .

Comment: If $x$ is irrational then $f(x,y)=0$ for all $y$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy .  and for rational x ?

Comment: For $x$ rational $f(x,y)=0$ almost everywhere (because the set of rationals has measure $0$).

Comment: To claim that answer 4 is true, one needs a different argument though.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f=0$ a.e. on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. Conclusion ?